# Why not label-success and label-danger classes getting applied in angular4 directive?

Tags: angular, directive, angular2-directives

I have a status directive, which applies a specific bootstrap label class depending on the @Input, when I apply label-success or label-danger its not working and when I apply label-info or label-warning it works.

```
  @Input() status: string;

  @HostBinding('class.label-danger') private default = true; //not working
  @HostBinding('class.label-success') private default = true; //not working
  @HostBinding('class.label-warning') private default = true; //working
  @HostBinding('class.label-info') private default = true; //working
```

Inside ngOnInit method I am changing the values to true or false depending on the status text.

```
  <span class="label" appStatus [status]="status.slug">
   {{ status.name }}
  </span>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Post a complete minimal example reproducting the problem.

Comment: Bootstrap 3.7 or 4.0? In bootstrap 4.0 renamed .label to .badge to disambiguate from the <label> element. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#labels-and-badges

Comment: I think some problem with the code I have written.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zta44k it works here